# Nav item separators - too tall not centered

Tags: html, css, alignment, border

I have to do some work on a nav menu and everything is good except the separators. Right now, they look like this:

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K0IiO.png)

I need those separators, which are borders, to be shorter and the text vertical centered/aligned but it's not working in CSS, which is:

```
#menu-item-2506 a{
font-size:10px;
border-right: 2px solid #000000;
height:45px;
padding-right:5px;
letter-spacing:2px;
vertical-align: center;
}
```

That's one of the items, but the code is the same for all, except the last child.

Any suggestions?

UPDATE - new image

[lowered height](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f3kD7.png)

Comment: Reduce the height to an appropriate level, for example `1em` (or similar).

Comment: I actually did try that and it looks like the updated image above

Comment: Is this menu in a seperate div? It'd be best if you could supply all the relevant HTML and CSS (everything to do with the menu) so we can help.

Comment: Then take the time to post your [mcve] HTML, as well as the CSS, in your question. Update the question to explain what you've already tried, and in what way those attempts failed.

Comment: it's part of a wordpress theme nav div, but I'm just doing some custom css

Comment: Is the parent `position:relative` or `absolute` or `fixed`? You could vertically center the text using flexbox or giving the container div the same padding-top and padding-bottom. Then position the lines `absolute`ly and give them something like `top:10px;bottom:10px`.
But like the others said, without knowing the HTML structure it's kind of hard to know which is the best way.

Answer (score 1):

Just apply line-height: 45px; if you know that your element is 45px height.
If you don't have to support older browsers, I would strongly suggest different approach with FLEX.

```css
#menu-item-2506{ /* ignore me, just basic improvisation. */
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  width: auto;
  height: 45px;
  background: #1d1d1d;
}
#menu-item-2506 a{
  line-height: 45px; /* USE THIS AND YOU'RE FINE IF YOU KNOW YOUR ELEMENT HEIGHT */
  font-size:10px;
  border-right: 2px solid #000000;
  height:45px;
  padding-right:5px;
  letter-spacing:2px;
  vertical-align: center;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<div id="menu-item-2506">
  <a href="#Bled_Slovenija">Bled Slovenija</a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Split style of "a" and #menu-item-2506 for better control and give right border only to "a", not div.

```
<style>
#menu-item-2506 {
font-size:10px;
height:45px;
padding-right:5px;
letter-spacing:2px;
vertical-align: center;
}

a {
font-size:10px;
padding-right:5px;
letter-spacing:2px;
border-right: 2px solid #000000;
vertical-align: center;
}


</style>

<div id="menu-item-2506">
<a href="#">Top</a>
</div>
```